# What could be a valid URI template for REST API handling a GET HTTP request with multiple parameters?

Tags: rest, api, web-services, restful-url

I am developing a RESTful API that handle a GET request needing 2 parameters.

I try to explain better the use case: This API will return the latest price of a specific commodity (the **commodity_id** is one parameter) in a specific market (the **market_id** is the second parameter).

So what can be a valid URI template for this pourpose?

Something like this:

```
/latest_commodity_price/{commodity_id}/{market_id}
```

or something like this:

```
/latest_commodity_price/{commodity_id}?market_id={market_id}
```

or something like:

```
/latest_commodity_price?commodity_id={commodity_id}&market_id={market_id}
```

Or what else?

Answer (score 3):

In RESTful ways your approach starts at the wrong position. REST means you are querying resources. So the URI should start with the resource you are querying your API for.

```
/commodity/{commondity_id}
```

Then you want to have a list of prices for a market. This sound like you query your API to retrieve a list of prices for the commodity:

```
/commodity/{commondity_id}/prices
```

Finally you are filtering the list of prices. I recommend doing filtering with the query parameters:

```
/commodity/{commondity_id}/prices?market_id={market_id}&latestPrice=1
```